# Git merge branch of another remote

Tags: linux, git, command-line

Nowadays, I see a lot of commits from Linus Torvalds and/or Gitster that look like so:

```
Merge branch 'maint' of git://github.com/git-l10n/git-po into maint …
* 'maint' of git://github.com/git-l10n/git-po:
  l10n: de.po: fix a few minor typos
```

or:

```
Merge branch 'upstream' of git://git.linux-mips.org/pub/scm/ralf/upst… …
…ream-linus

Pull MIPS update from Ralf Baechle:
...
* 'upstream' of git://git.linux-mips.org/pub/scm/ralf/upstream-linus: (22 commits)
  MIPS: SNI: Switch RM400 serial to SCCNXP driver
...
```

I have no idea how would one do that, although, I know about the **git remote** and **git checkout** and **git merge** that I use to merge forks (or "pull requests") but it does not generate such message, why? and how would someone do that (provide examples please)?

P.S: I'm a fan of Linus Torvalds commits etc, like how detailed the description of his merges look ;P

P.S: This is how I used to merge stuff:

```
git remote add anotherremoot
git checkout -b anotherbranch
git pull remoteshortcut
...do tests...
git checkout master
git merge anotherbranch
git push
```

The above example I learned from: http://viget.com/extend/i-have-a-pull-request-on-github-now-what

Comment: It's Linus Torvalds. Please correct the first line of your post :)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Just use [`git pull`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html) to pull the remote branch into `master`:

```
git remote add something git://host.example.com/path/to/repo.git
git checkout master
git pull something master
```

Or do it without adding a remote:

```
git pull git://host.example.com/path/to/repo.git
```

`git pull` fetches the remote branch, and merges it into the local branch. If possible, it does a fast-forward merge, which just means that it updates the current master to the latest commit without generating a merge commit. But if there are changes on both sides, it will do a merge, like the ones you see Linus and Junio doing, with the remote URL included.

If you want to guarantee that you get a merge commit, even if it could fast forward, do `git pull -no-ff`. If you want to make sure that `pull` never creates a merge commit (so fails if there are changes on both sides), do `git pull --ff-only`.

If you want to include a more detailed message, like the full log that Linus provides, do `git pull --log`. If you want to edit the message, instead of just using the automatically created message, use `git pull --edit`. See [documentation for `git pull`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html) for more options.

Comment: I'm curious why `git merge` doesn't work here. Anybody knows?

Comment: @NickRibal Plain old merge will result in `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`, but we can merge with `git merge otherremote/otherbranch --allow-unrelated-histories`. Can confirm I have done this and it works fine.