# How to merge branch of forked repo into master branch of original repo?

Tags: git, github, git-merge

There is an open source project on GitHub. Its original repo contains the most recent master branch. Now there is someone (not me) who has forked this repo, created a development branch from the master branch and added stuff to the development branch. What I would like to do now is to merge the development branch back to the master branch. Unfortunately, the master branch of the forked repo is not up-to-date. Also note that I'm not in possession of the two respective remote repos.

At the moment, I have cloned both the original repo and the forked repo to my local machine using `git clone`. How can I merge the development branch of the forked repo into the master branch of the original repo on my local machine (i.e. not on the remote server which is not possible anyway)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git merge branch of another remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921125/git-merge-branch-of-another-remote)

Answer (score 44):

When using GitHub, you could do this using a [**Pull Request**](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests). Simply push your development branch to the forked remote repository and create the pull request as described in the linked article. The owner of the original repository can then add your repository as a new remote repository, fetch your changes and merge your development branch back into the master branch.

It is usually not necessary for your master branch to be fully up-to-date -- although it is extremly helpful, especially when merging the development branch.

First, you should bring the `master` branch in the forked repository up-to-date:

```sh
$ git remote add upstream ssh://path/to/original/repo
$ git checkout master
$ git fetch upstream # Instead of "fetch" & "merge", "pull" would also work
$ git merge upstream/master
```

Then either `rebase` or `merge` your development branch into the master branch:

```sh
$ git checkout development
$ git rebase master # OR "git merge master"
```

Resolve any conflicts, if necessary. When merging, use `git commit` to finish the merge, when rebasing use `git commit && git rebase --continue`.

You should now be able to `git push` to the origin of the forked repository, and create a pull request. Alternatively, if you're authorized to do so, you can also push directly to the original repository from your fork.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood something. It's not me who forked the original repo and created the development branch. Also, I don't want to push the merged changes back to remote. It's just for local work. How can I do it without my own fork and without doing a pull request?

Comment: For the scenario you're describing, regular branches should be fine. You can easily branch out in order to develop a new feature while main branch will be continued. After you're feature is finished, you've to merge it back into the master.

Comment: @ThorstenHans You've apparently misunderstood me as well. I'm neither in possession of the original nor the forked repo. I just cloned both of them to my local machine. The forked repo contains a branch that contains a feature which I want to merge into the master branch of the original repo.

Comment: @PeterStahl So you want to locally merge the development branch from the forked repository with the master branch of the original repository? That's exactly what I described in my answer (except that you can ignore everything that I wrote about pull requests and pushing).

Comment: @helmbert Indeed, it was actually me who misunderstood you, not vice versa. Sorry. I was just confused by your statements about `git push` and pull requests. I've just tried out your steps and they seem to work. I'll just make some more tests before I decide to accept your answer. Anyway, thank you. :)

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you've already cloned both repositories. I'm going to assume you have them in directories `clone1` and `clone2`.

You need to get all the changesets into one repository before you can do the merge. So we're going to pull from one of your clones into the other one. Were you doing this from scratch, you would just clone *one* repository and then fetch the other, instead of cloning both.

1. `cd clone1`
2. `git checkout master`
3. `git remote add clone2 ../clone2` (put both remotes into one repo). If you hadn't cloned both repositories, you wouldn't have to do this - you'd just do `git remote add otherthing https://<github URI>`
4. `git fetch` (fetch changes from `clone2` into `clone1`). Now you have one repository with everything.
5. `git checkout origin/master` Or you can check out a local branch. Your preference. Remember, `origin` here refers to the source for `clone1`.
6. `git merge clone2/development` If necessary, resolve conflicts at this point. Commit the result.
7. `git checkout -b my-ongoing-development` (name the branch you just made, which contains both remote branches)

Comment: In your 6th point. `git merge clone2/development`, is clone2 the remote? For me the 6th point doesn't work, hence asking. **merge: thdn - not something we can merge**. thdn is my remote name instead of clone2

Comment: `clone2` is the remote name. `clone2/development` is the `development` branch of the local reflection of the `clone2` repository. Merge accepts a "refspec" as its argument. `clone2/development` is a valid refspec. I have no idea what command you're actually running locally, but I suspect you messed up somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

The previous comment is close, except step 6 should be

`git pull clone2 development`

Refer to [Git merge branch of another remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921125/git-merge-branch-of-another-remote)

Answer (score 0):

GitHub allows you to merge branches across forks.

Clicking on that shows you also all related forks:

[image]

You could also rebuild this behaviour in the URL. Example:

```
https://github.com/holzkohlengrill/rust-by-example/compare/master...ehuss:rust-by-example:fix-ci
```